# How to connect to oracle from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have problem with connecting to Oracle from Sql developer. When I try this connection settings. it returns error from printscreen:[image]

when I tried tns ping, it returns to me

```
C:\Windows\system32>tnsping XE

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-APR-2021 23:47:25

Copyright (c) 1997, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (0 msec)
```

Can someone give me a point what I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

l

```
snrctl status is C:\Windows\system32> lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 09-APR-2021 23:57:42

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                09-APR-2021 23:09:50
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 47 min. 52 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\PoŔÝtaŔ\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

When I tryed to change to Sid, it returns me:
[image]

when I try to

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl reload

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 10-APR-2021 00:10:54

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
The command completed successfully
```

But problem is still same: [image]

I tried lsnrctl status and It return to me

```
C:\Users\Uzivatel>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 10-APR-2021 02:01:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                10-APR-2021 00:44:34
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 16 min. 45 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\PoŔÝtaŔ\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=PoŔÝtaŔ)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

it seems that there is some problem, isnt it?

Comment: What's the output of `lsnrctl status` ? Have you already tried using `SID`, instead of `SERVICE_NAME`?

Comment: lsnrctl status is

Comment: I Add lsnrctl status to my question

Comment: It looks like either your database is not running, or it is not able to register its service(s) with the listener. Is the Oracle DB Windows service running; and if so can you connect locally through SQL\*Plus?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I wrongly supposed your Database was running.

Start your database by issuing a `startup`

```
CMD> sqlplus /as sysdba

SQL> startup
```

Before attempting to connect, check your listener with `lsnrctl status` you should now see the `XE` service there.

If everything's in place, you should then be able to connect.

---

As far as I can see, there's no service named `XE`

You can either connect by selecting `SID` instead of `SERVICE NAME`

Or try to add a static registration to your listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )
)
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
 (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC=
     (SID_NAME=XE)
     (SERVICE_NAME=XE)
     (ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\Uzivatel\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
   )
 )
```

Reload the listener

```
lsnrctl reload
```

And then try to connect via SQL Developer, using the `SERVICE NAME`

Another thing you can try, is getting inside the Database and issue a

```
alter system register;
```

To see if the database register against the listener by itself.

Comment: I add comment to my question

Comment: my bad, removed the `EXTPROC1` thing, didn't mean to be there... edit the listener.ora with the new configuration and try reloading the listener again.

Comment: I remove it, but problem is still same.

Comment: Is your Database in an `OPEN` state? Can you connect to it via the command line `sqlplus /as sysdba` for example?

Comment: it returns me Connected to an idle instance.. I have to use startup to connect to database with sql plus.

Comment: You need to startup your database, in order to connect to it via SQL Developer. Issue a `startup` and after that you should be able to connect.

Comment: Unfortunetelly not. Is there some command how to open database?

Comment: `startup` is the command to open the database. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried to run lsnrctl status, and result is in my question. But it seems that there is some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "XE" is your services name??
Try selecting SID and set a name to the connection

Comment: Im sure that XE is my service name. I tryed it with Sid, but without sucess, see printscreen in my guestion.

Comment: Now I facing this error : TNS-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00534: Failed to grant connection ownership to child
   64-bit Windows Error: 10022: Unknown error

Comment: you should have installed a 32 bits and 64 bits client to avoid that

Comment: I have installed 64bits client, but error is still same.

Comment: You did try to install a second time in custom mode selecting the products components that you need?

Comment: I have installed 64b client. What else shoul I need?